# How can I move the red, yellow and green buttons a few pixels to the bottom and to the right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mac-catalyst

In short, when adding a toolbar it changes the styling of the window spacing the three buttons appropriately. How can I achieve the same effect without having to add a toolbar?

[image]

I can't use an empty toolbar because the ultimate goal is to create a completely different looking toolbar. [Unfortunately, since I'm using a Mac Catalyst app I can't customize the toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72257998/how-can-i-customize-an-nstoolbaritem-to-make-it-look-completely-different) but I still need it to look like as if a toolbar was there for aesthetic reasons.

"Notability" which is a popular note-taking app featured in the official [WWDC2021 video](https://youtu.be/NOksJH-BXrc?t=80) is having the same problem.

[image]

There is no toolbar in the Mac Catalyst version of Notability. The title bar is hidden. The content is moved slightly to the bottom to create more space and custom views are placed above making it look like a toolbar.

[image]

On the left is how it looks like. On the right is how it should look like (I photoshopped it) and what I'm trying to achieve. It's very easy to not fix it and leave it this way since hiding the title bar can happen with a few lines of code:

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    
#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
    // Code specific to Mac.
    
    [(UIWindowScene*)scene titlebar].separatorStyle = UITitlebarSeparatorStyleNone;
    [(UIWindowScene*)scene titlebar].titleVisibility = UITitlebarTitleVisibilityHidden;

#else
    // Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif

}
```

Is there any chance I can hack my way through it by for example using a split view that never splits or some other UI element or setting hidden or not?

Comment: Are there any applications that look the way you're asking about?

Comment: Like, all of them.

Comment: But they do have a toolbar.

Comment: The App Store seems to not have a toolbar and still look this way but it does have a split view.

Comment: Let's be serious. I'm asking for examples of what you're describing, ie without a toolbar and without a split view. In other words, can you demonstrate that this is possible at all?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. No. And I don't have an example where it looks like it has been achieved this way but even if I had one I wouldn't know for sure if it has a toolbar or not unless I message the developer.

Comment: What's the problem with adding an empty toolbar if it gets you the result you want?

Comment: The problem with the empty toolbar is that I can't create a custom NSToolbarItem because I'm using MacCatalyst and the "view" property of the NSToolbarItem isn't accessible to me. I can't add a subview on top of it either. I will have to make a native Mac app or figure out a way to fake it.  I'm trying to make enough space where the titlebar should have been and put my custom made toolbar bellow. It's a hack that 100% WORKS but the red, yellow and green dots look misplaced. If only they could move a few pixels to the right and to the bottom.

Comment: What if I add a split view that never gets split?

Comment: You can see my frustration with the hidden "view" from non-native/catalyst Mac apps in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72257998/how-can-i-customize-an-nstoolbaritem-to-make-it-look-completely-different

Comment: FOUND IT. Someone tried to "fake it" the way I'm trying to. The app is named "Notability" and it's in the OFFICIAL APPLE VIDEO: https://youtu.be/NOksJH-BXrc?t=83 Just look how misplaced the dots are. They are making room for their custom toolbar bellow while the dots are anchored on the top left looking weirdly misplaced.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear. There is no toolbar in the video I posted. It's all trickery. The title bar is hidden. The content view is moved slightly to the bottom to create more space and custom views are placed above making it look like a toolbar.

Comment: @Vulkan Is it possible to set the TitleBarToolbarStyle even without a toolbar? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uititlebartoolbarstyle https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uititlebar/3604076-toolbarstyle

Comment: I tried setting it but nothing changed. It remains the same unless I initialize the toolbar and assign it to the scene's titlebar. I also tried to add a toolbar and then removing it by setting it to "nil" but still nothing...